# Receiv boolean result to see if crontab exists

Tags: python, bash, raspberry-pi

In Python or Bash, is there an easy way to receive a Boolean result on whether or not the crontab exists?

```
crontab -e #shows me manually
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `crontab -l` command displays your crontab.  If you have no crontab, it will display `no crontab for <username>` on `stderr` and exit with error code 1.

If you have an empty crontab, it will display no errors and will exit with a status code of 0.

So if you want to check for empty OR does-not-exist, you can just see if `crontab -l` produces any output:

```
if [ $(crontab -l | wc -c) -eq 0 ]; then
  echo crontab is empty
fi
```

If you want to check explicitly for an *absent* crontab, then

```
if ! crontab -l; then
  echo you have no crontab
fi
```

Comment: Thanks this is working for me. I'm getting the standard message also "no crontab for root". Is there a way to suppress this message?

Comment: Sure, redirect *stderr* to `/dev/null`.  So `crontab -l 2> /dev/null`, for example.